# using numeric as enum key

Tags: java, jsp, enums

Due to an unavoidable circumstance, I need to create an enum class like below,

```
public enum Region
{
 1("Region1"),
 2("Region2");
}
```

But I'm getting an error as "Syntax error on token '1', identifier expected". This enum is used in an option tag in jsp. It works fine if use a string instead of 1, enum doesn't allow numeric as keys ?

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are invalid as identifiers in Java. Typically [uppercase letters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are used when defining enum constants

Answer (score 1):

The first character of any identifier has to be a letter. From the [JLS section 3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier) (emphasis mine):

> An *identifier* is an unlimited-length sequence of *Java letters* and *Java digits*, **the first of which must be a *Java letter***.
>
> [...]
>
> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns `true`.
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Digits are not allowed, so you can't name your enum values `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use numeric as the enum names.
Maybe you can do

```
public enum Region {
  ONE("region1"),
  TWO("region2");
}
```